# Setting username MySQL result as variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently using a text file which contains a bunch of usernames, instead of the text file I want my script to run through a mysql column instead.

Is the line I'm having trouble with, I'm wondering if I could use the result of mysql query as the variable?

```
$name = file("/var/www/html/memberlist/memberlist.txt");
```

Here's my  full code if needed

```
<?php
include 'dbopen.php';

function get_web_page($url) {
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Highscores grabber v1.0",
CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10
);
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
$err = curl_errno( $ch );
$errmsg = curl_error( $ch );
$header = curl_getinfo( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
return $content;
}

function getStats($name)
{
    $skills = array('Overall', 'Attack', 'Defence', 'Strength', 'Hitpoints', 'Ranged', 'Prayer', 'Magic', 'Cooking', 'Woodcutting', 'Fletching', 'Fishing', 'Firemaking', 'Crafting', 'Smithing', 'Mining', 'Herblore', 'Agility', 'Thieving', 'Slayer', 'Farming', 'Runecrafting', 'Hunter', 'Construction');
    $hs = get_web_page("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=$name");
        $out = Array();
        $stats = explode("\n", $hs);
                for($i = 0; $i<count($skills);$i++) {
                        $stat = explode(',', $stats[$i]);
                        $out[$skills[$i]] = Array();
                        $out[$skills[$i]]['rank'] = $stat[0];
                        $out[$skills[$i]]['level'] = $stat[1];
                        $out[$skills[$i]]['xp'] = $stat[2];
                }
    return $out;
}

$name = file("/var/www/html/memberlist/memberlist.txt");

for($j=0;isset($name[$j]);$j++)
{
    $out[$j] = getStats($name[$j]);
}

if (!empty($out))
{
    for($k=0;isset($out[$k]);$k++)
    {       

        $hitpointsexp = $out[$k]['Hitpoints']['xp'];
        $rangedexp = $out[$k]['Ranged']['xp'];    
        $magicexp = $out[$k]['Magic']['xp'];   
        $rsn = trim($name[$k]);


        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }

        // Perform queries 
        $query= ("
        INSERT INTO 
            gains (runescape_name, hitpoints_starting_exp, magic_starting_exp, range_starting_exp) 
        VALUES 
            ('" . $rsn . "',  '" . $hitpointsexp . "', '" . $magicexp . "', '" . $rangedexp . "') 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            hitpoints_starting_exp='$hitpointsexp', magic_starting_exp='$magicexp', range_starting_exp='$rangedexp'
        ");
        $result = mysql_query($query);


    }
}
?>
```

Comment: it's really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry Augwa, does that explain it a little better?

Comment: I'm currently using a text file which contains a bunch of usernames, instead of the text file I want my script to run through a mysql column instead.

I'm wondering if I could use the result of mysql query as the variable?

Comment: @user3948234: Yes, you can.

Comment: How would I go about this?